# Drupal 6.22 Custom Page Not Displaying

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-panels

I have just migrated a Drupal site to a new Windows Server 2012 IIS8 server.

The migration went fine and the database and all files copied across fine and I was able to log in and so on. However one thing is not working and its driving me nuts.

The home page is not displaying the panel content that it should. The home page should display for instance the log-in form widget. I have tried absolutely everything, I have deleted the panel and recreated it, checked permissions and even deleted the page and recreated it from scratch but all to no avail. If I create a custom page and add any content to it even simple content only the page title displays with no content displayed below. The div areas are there but are all empty.

Watchdog shows nothing at all out of the ordinary and the php log on the server is also working but empty.

I wonder if any Drupal guru might be able to shed some light on this for me before I loose what little hair I have left.

Comment: How is this question related to Drupal 7?

Comment: @Oswald Well being a drupal issue, It may have also cropped up in a drupal 7 release, so to raise the possibility of getting some relevant answers from the maximum audience I also tagged drupal 7. In any case if the question does not interest you, you could just ignore it rather than spending time asking questions which are obviously meant to be of a pointed nature.